# Can I visit France with a Portuguese visa if I haven't yet been to to Portugal?

Tags: visas, schengen

Long story short, my trip to Portugal was cancelled due to personal reasons and so I have yet to use the Schengen visa to enter the zone. Now I want to visit France but I'm scared I'll get rejected, fined or blacklisted as it might be seems as breaking the rules, when in reality it's circumstancial.

Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Is this a single entry visa or the first visit on a multiple entry visa?